# Yocto, how to add libmosquitto in Target

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, libmosquitto, yocto-recipe

The [Open Embedded Mosquitto recipe](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/156726/) installs mosquitto as a deamon, but there is no libmosquitto.so on the Target.

How can I modify the recipe to install the libs?

Already created `mosquitto_%.bbappend` and try to extend the `do_install` function with something like this.

```
    do_install_append() {
        install -m 0755 ${FILES_libmosquitto1} ${D}${libdir}/
    }
```

**edit:**

Digged a little deeper and found that libmosquitto.so is available in build and in image direcory, just as the Layer shippes. So I must be missing something when creating the rootfs.

```sh
bitbake mosquitto -c configure
bitbake mosquitto -c compile
bitbake mosquitto -c install

WORKDIR=./build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mosquitto/1.6.12-r0

# lib is available in after do_compile
cd ${WORKDIR}/build/lib
tree
├── libmosquitto.so -> libmosquitto.so.1
├── libmosquitto.so.1 -> libmosquitto.so.1.6.12
└── libmosquitto.so.1.6.12

# lib is available after do_install, also headers and binary is available (in include, sbin respectively)
cd ${WORKDIR}/image/usr/lib
tree
├── libmosquitto.so -> libmosquitto.so.1
├── libmosquitto.so.1 -> libmosquitto.so.1.6.12
└── libmosquitto.so.1.6.12
```

Comment: First of all try to compile it on your own and see is and where *libmosquitto.so* file is creating during the build. Then you can create bbappend file similarly to yours example above.

Comment: @kluszon, thanks for pointing me into that direction. That helped me to figure out that the libs actually existst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And to complete my rubberduck debugging, its as simple as adding the right Package to `IMAGE_INSTALL`

- `mosquitto`, installs the server
- `libmosquitto1`, `libmosquittopp1`, installs the library (`libmosquitto` does not work)
- `mosquitto-clients`, installs the mosquitto_pub, _sub commands

So just add the wished packages to `IMAGE_INSTALL`

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " \
                    libmosquitto1 \
                    libmosquittopp1 \
"
```